# Shuffling two files and merge data

Tags: text-processing

For Example: I have two files

**input.txt**

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

**output.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to merge these two files and to get another output file (e.g, match.txt) like this,

```
one 1
two 2
three 3
...
```

Moreover, when I shuffle these two .txt files randomly, the output file (match.txt) will also merge the correct data like that...

```
three 3
two 2
five 5
...
```

How can I write shell script?

Comment: You need to be clear if the numbers are examples, or specific.  Do you always want the word `one` to be following by the number `1`, and in the output file, the order is based on the words?  Or are they examples of other possible values in some way, in which case, it needs more detail.

Answer (score 5):

Simply with **`paste`** command:

```
paste -d' ' input.txt output.txt > match.txt
```

The `match.txt` content:

```
one 1
two 2
three 3
four 4
five 5
```

---

With *shuffling* (via **`sort`** command):

```
paste -d' ' input.txt output.txt | sort -R
```

An exemplary output:

```
two 2
four 4
one 1
three 3
five 5
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what the OP describes. Shuffle file 1, then shuffle file2 and at the end match the two suffled files together but in the correct logical way like `two 2`. Is a nice  exercise.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, It's obvious that that scheme that you described requires a **predefined** "mapping" of logical pairs `{"one": 1, "two": 2, ...}`. That's not the case. And what if the input list contains the items from `one` to `ninety`? What would be your answer for such **nice exercise**?

Comment: I fully agree. Even my answer is based in a predifined mapping. I can not think any other "programming" way to match `one` with `1`. Sorry, i didn't want to be frustrating - it just sounded a nice exercise to match `one` with `1`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, that's ok

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input.txt
five
one
three
two
four

$ awk 'BEGIN{a["one"]=1;a["two"]=2;a["three"]=3;a["four"]=4;a["five"]=5}$0 in a{print $0,a[$0]}' input.txt
five 5
one 1
three 3
two 2
four 4
```